# tooltip doesn't work when I include bootstrap with npm

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, frontend, tooltip, web-deployment

I have a page, when I include bootstrap JS with npm like this

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/poppor.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

, tootip doesn't work, but when I include Bootstrap JS like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It works well.

Here is where I use tooltip

```
<a href="#reserve-table" role="button" 
                data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Or Call us at <br><strong>+852 12345678</strong>"
                class="btn btn-block btn-warning nav-link">
                    Reserve Table
                </a>
```

I don't know why as I'm beginner to bootstrap, and also what is the best way of including bootstrap respect to site load speed, and what is the way people used to do it?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if the question may seem silly.

**Update:**
I notice someone also have the same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593705/tooltip-bootstrap-doesnt-work), the answer said to add bootstrap from external resources and tooltip will work fine, but it doesn't said why!

**Update:**
The problem has been solved when I replace the file

```
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I don't know why!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there might be something off with the way you're including popper in your project as evidenced by:

1. The fact that the combined Popper/Bootstrap import solved your problem. According to [Bootstrap's NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap):

> Bundled JS files (bootstrap.bundle.js and minified bootstrap.bundle.min.js) include Popper, but not jQuery.

2. Your script `src` is `node_modules/popper.js...` when that package is listed as [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js/v/1.14.3). Consider using `@popperjs/core`, instead. (Assuming that `poppor.js` at the end of that `src` is a transcribing error and that the actual `src` ends with `popper`)

Comment: So why people could include popper when they  can include bootstrap.bundle.js which itself include popper? this is why I asked what is the best practice for including these files

Comment: Also I want to note that including @popper/js doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your question on "best practice". Best practice for including bootstrap on a static site is to use a CDN as per your example under, "tootip doesn't work, but when I include Bootstrap JS like this"